# How do I open cmd.exe and execute a command?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

So I want to set the system volume to 25% through a batch file. 
I managed to open cmd.exe using:

```
start cmd
```

however when I add the command:

```
start cmd /k echo nircmd.exe setsysvolume 16384
```

it types it into the cmd window, but doesn't actually execute the command. It's hard to explain, but it's like the text is written before the command line interface actually begins taking commands. What results is:

```
nircmd.exe setsysvolume 16834
C:\Users\User\Desktop>
```

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: You are running the `echo` command, which prints the line to the screen.  Remove `echo`.

Comment: You also do not need to use `START` or `CMD` to execute `nircmd.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo nircmd.exe setsysvolume 1638 > foo.bat && start cmd /k foo.bat
```

You also can run it this way

```
echo nircmd.exe setsysvolume 1638 > foo.bat && start cmd /c foo.bat
```

so that the new command window closes when foo.bat has finished or just

```
echo nircmd.exe setsysvolume 1638 > foo.bat && foo.bat
```

to run foo.bat directly.

Comment: Not sure why you would redirect to a bat file and then execute the bat file. Seems like it would be just easier to just execute the command.

Comment: I don't know why the questioner want to do that. I just answered the question